# How trino deals with null owner?

Tags: trino

I have some logic that create a view in trino. The view owner is `null`, not `"null"` but true `null` value. How does trino deal with it?

For example, if view owner is `user1` and this view access table with owner `user2` there can be a problem with different access rights. But what about `null` owner? Is there a way to set access right for this owner?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the security setting of the view. Use SHOW CREATE VIEW to find out the setting.

If its invoker then the permissions from whoever is querying the view kick in.

If its set definer and the owner is a null value .. then no access rights are passed on (or it might even fail).

In either case .. it will also largely depend on what access control you have in place to even support the authorization. Out of the box there is none in Trino.

Find more in the documentation starting at  https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/create-view.html